# Position of label to pop up

Tags: html, css, graphics

I'm having trouble with centering a label to a pop up when clicked.
I've tried different option on positioning and can get it centered on the top of the list with no luck. The more I move the label, the more it moves from the center of the pop up.

The goal is once clicked, the label shifts from the side of the button to the top of pop up.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  font-size: 9pt;
  margin-bottom: 1pt;
  margin-top: 2.5pt;
  margin-left: 2px;
  z-index: 5;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

label {
  font-size: 10pt;
  margin-bottom: 0pt;
  margin-top: 12pt;
  margin-left: 14px;
  color: #e26030;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*
        .centered {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
*/

.test {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  right: 2px;
}

.centered-y {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
}

.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
  border: 2.5px solid #e26030;
}

.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #afe1fa;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="distribution-map">
    <button class="map-point" id="one" style="top:130%;left:39%">
        <label class="test" for="one">TOP</label>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="centered-y">
            <p><a href="">Sub1</a></p>
            <p>Sub2</p>
            <p>Sub3</p>
            <p>Sub4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `margin-left: 14px;` property of label , after removing it `.test` is centered but you have to change position of dot

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  font-size: 9pt;
  margin-bottom: 1pt;
  margin-top: 2.5pt;
  margin-left: 2px;
  z-index: 5;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

label {
  font-size: 10pt;
  margin-bottom: 0pt;
  margin-top: 12pt;
  /*margin-left: 14px;*/
  color: #e26030;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*
        .centered {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
*/

.test {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  right: 2px;
}

.centered-y {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
}

.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
  border: 2.5px solid #e26030;
}

.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #afe1fa;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="distribution-map">
    <button class="map-point" id="one" style="top:130%;left:39%">
        <label class="test" for="one">TOP</label>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="centered-y">
            <p><a href="">Sub1</a></p>
            <p>Sub2</p>
            <p>Sub3</p>
            <p>Sub4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried changing the position of the Dot, but the label follows it.

Comment: Then will be hard as the whole code you have written is known better by you, let see what extent I can help . I will comment further if got any progress